# How to stop subprocess from terminating my script?

Tags: python, subprocess

Whenever I am trying to run a shell script using `subprocess.call()` or `os.system()`, the script runs, but the Python script also terminates and everything written after the call never executes. I have tried importing this call from a library and running or executing it from a separate python script using `execfile()` but same thing happened there too. Is there something wrong with my system, or is this how it is supposed to be? If the latter, then how shall I stop this and keep my Python script running after making this subprocess/system call?

```
shushens@P600:~/Desktop$ python
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:03:08) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(["sh","test.sh"])
shushens@P600:~/Desktop$
```

This is the shell script:

```
export <SOMEPATHNAME>=/some/path/here
exec $SHELL -i
```

I think it is the `exec $SHELL -i` that is causing all programs running on that particular shell to terminate. But I do not know what other alternative I have. The `export` does not work if I do not use it. Currently, the path I want to export is exporting, but the Python process gets terminated along with it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show your script. You probably do not catch an occuring exception.

Comment: SHOW...CODE. Only you know the context of this question. The rest of us don't know what you are actually trying and what the result is.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in adding it. I already have added the code.

Comment: You have too many mysteries in your code. `export` shouldn't require `exec` to work. What were you using instead of `exec` that was breaking your script? Fix your bugs as you go along (in this case, test.sh), don't wait until you can no longer tell what needs fixing.

Comment: That is the thing. If I simply comment that exec statement, and run the shell script, and look into my environment variables using `env`, it does not show the path I set!

Comment: I think the biggest problem here is that your goal is unclear. As pointed out by other comments, your code is working as expected, yet its not clear WHY you want to start an interactive shell from the python script. Maybe you should think about updating your question to have a straight foward goal.

Answer (score 3):

The shell isn't killing your script, it's doing exactly what you ask it to do, start a new interactive bash session. Notice that after the call to subprocess if I do a ps, python is still running. Further more if you exit the bash session it takes you back into the python interpreter/script.

```
bago@bago-laptop:~$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['sh', 'test.sh'])
bago@bago-laptop:~$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1412 pts/3    00:00:00 bash
 1485 pts/3    00:00:00 python
 1486 pts/3    00:00:00 bash
 1509 pts/3    00:00:00 ps
bago@bago-laptop:~$ exit
exit
0
>>> print "im back in python"
"im back in python"
>>> exit()
```

Export shouldn't need you start a new bash session to work. I'm  not sure why you're using export but have you considered `os.environ['SOMEPATHNAME'] = "/some/path/here"`. This will set the environment variable in  your python script before you use `subprocess.call`.

Comment: Yes I have tried, but I wanted to set an environment variable that is persistent across the whole system. Is there some other way I can invoke a shell script that sets a variable that is persistent across the system?

Comment: Persistent across the whole system? Meaning you change the variable in one script and it also changes in another, already running script? I'm not sure that's possible (and it doesn't sound like a good idea).

Comment: Yes, I want it to be permanently set. If I open any other shell and query `env | grep "variablename"`, I should see that result.

Comment: I think you're a little confused about what environment variables are and how to use them, take a look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Working_principles_of_environment_variables
Environment variable are inherited by child processes by default, but changing an environment variable in a processes shouldn't change that variable in the parent process or other running processes.

Comment: Running with root privileges also does not help? I do know what environment variables are. And when I set one from command line, it is persistent system-wide. If I run a Python script with same privileges, is it impossible to make it persistent system-wide?

Comment: @SubhamoySengupta: You are mistaken about this. Using `export` from a shell to set an env does not make it a system-wide effect. It is only valid for the life of that shell process and its subprocesses. If you open a new shell, that env is not persistant. Setting these values in a shell profile would allow them to be set for every shell session, as it will be initialized when they start.